# Eclipse PHP IDE annoyance

Tags: eclipse, phpeclipse

This is such a petty little issue, but it annoys the heck out of me.  I'm using Eclipse Version: 3.3.0 (Build id: I20070625-1500).  In particular, PHPeclipse 1.2.0.200807121925PRD.

So here's the issue, when I'm within an echo " "; statement (typing some markup within the quotation marks to output) and hit return, Eclipse automatically terminates the line I'm on with:

> " .

... and then precedes my cursor on the next line with:

> "

This is not the behavior that I want.  I'd prefer it simply didn't do this at all.  But for the life of me I can't figure out where in the Eclipse preferences I can alter this behavior.

I realize there may be some out there who would argue in favor of this default behavior.  I'm less interested in those arguments than I am in how to control this behavior of the IDE.

Comment: yeah.. I find it iritating as well.. i have been searching for a switch for ages, to no avail..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure which exact setting it might be, but try Window->Preferences->PHP->Editor and either ->Code Assist or ->Typing. You might find something there that will help you change the setting. Edit: It *might* be the Automatically Close Strings checkbox under ->Typing.

Comment: close enough to get me there! it was window->preferences->PHPeclipse->PHP->Typing->Wrap double-quoted PHP strings. unchecked and working as desired now. THANK YOU!

Comment: brilliant. am much happier now